# Maven parent dynamic packagingtype pom

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am building a micro service project using maven (pom parent). We have another pom that reads this project pom to create jenkins build (pom child). Since it is the parent project, the packaging type is pom. We do not use Jenkins build pom in our local nor have access to it.

The issue is to have it run on local we change the package type to jar and during deployment manually change it to pom. Sometimes it happen the jar is pushed and we get errors in the build. To over come this, I created profiles.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>BUILD</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>pom</packaging.type>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>LOCAL</id>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
        </properties>
            </profile>
      </profiles>.
```

and referred by

```
<packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>
```

This work fine in local but when it is pushed for Jenkins build, it get an errror as it does not read the packaging Type.

Is there a better design or solution to this.

Comment: Sound very wrong. Can you more in detail describe what the problem is? Having a parent is a good idea to move default versions of dependencies via dependencyManagement into this etc. furthermore defining plugin versions...But why do you need to change the packaging of your project?

Comment: As I said the parent pom is the project pom built by developers. There is a wrapper pom for Jenkins built which is written by Dev Ops Team. So for them the project parent pom needs to have packaging type pom. While for developers who run on their local using the project pom, need packaing type as jar. The issue is the child pom does not read the value of ${packagingType} as jar or pom.

Comment: There is something wrong...a wrapper pom sounds weird...Creating a simply pom which inherits from parent pom and define the packaging you need in the appropiate project...that's it..no need to go such weird paths...